# How to know if a property is a type of List<MyClass>?

Tags: c#, reflection, collections

I have this in these classes.

```
public class MyClass:BaseClass
{ }

public class BaseClass
{ }

public class CollectionClass
{
   public string SomeProperty {get; set;}

   public List<MyClass> Collection {get; set;}
}
```

In my code I want to find out if the property in some object (e. g. `CollectionClass`)  is a type of `List<BaseClass>` also I want to return true if the property is a type of `List<MyClass>`. The code below explains that.

```
public bool ContainsMyCollection(object obj)
{
   foreach(var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
   {
      //  Idk how to accomplish that
      if(property isTypeof List<BaseClass>)
         return true;
   }
   return false
}
```

Comment: I wrote an answer, but I think I misunderstood so I've now deleted it. You understand that `List<MyClass>` isn't a derived type of `List<BaseClass>`, right? `List<BaseClass> a = new List<MyClass>()` won't work, for example.

Comment: `if(property.PropertyType == typeof(List<BaseClass>))` but it's not clear what you actually want to achieve

Comment: Maybe better to explain why you want this rather than what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if you have a closed type of `List<>`. This can be done like so:

```
if(property.PropertyType.IsGenericType
    && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
```

and then you have to check if the generic argument (the `T` part of `List<T>`) is assignable to your base type:

```
if (typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]))
```

Putting that together, you get this:

```
public bool ContainsMyCollection(object obj)
{
   foreach(var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
   {
      //  Idk how to accomplish that
      if(property.PropertyType.IsGenericType 
         && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)
         && typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]))
      {
          return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Note that, as explained in the comments, `List<MyClass>` isn't derived from `List<BaseClass>`, even if `MyClass` is derived from `BaseClass`. So, for example, `List<BaseClass> a = new List<MyClass>();` will fail. That falls outside the scope of your question, but I figured I'd give you the heads up in case you didn't already know.